# Conversión de fecha en Formato Unixtime a fecha

Tags: django, date

Hoy traigo una pregunta espero que más interesante.  Os cuento, tengo una conexión a una *BBDD Mysql* obtenida con `inspectdb`, me ha traído la estructura de las tablas; que lo único que hago es consultarlas; pero tengo la mala suerte que los campos de fecha en esas tablas están en modo *UnixTime* y *Django* los ha visto como `BigIntegerField`, os pego unos ejemplos procedentes del **`models.py`** de la app:

```
startdate = models.BigIntegerField()
enddate = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Al mostrarlos en la template, he usado el filtro date, tal que así:

```
<td>{{object.enddate|date:'U'}}</td>
```

Pero no me muestra nada, evidentemente, si quito el filtro, me muestra el contenido numérico del campo.

He estado mirando datetime, pero en principio, no encuentro como aplicarlo a la cuestión, porque esta template la usa una vista DetailView, estoy pensando en modificar el models.py correspondiente a esta tabla para hacer que haga un return de los campos ya "tuneados" a fecha, o sobreescribir algún método de la detailview para convertir de unixtime a fecha humana.

¿Se os ocurre una buena solución?

Gracias por vuestro tiempo y un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Yo mismo me contesto, al final, cree un filtro personalizado tal que así:

filtro custom_template_tag.py:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

from datetime import datetime

@register.filter
def timestamp_to_date(value):
       return datetime.fromtimestamp(value)
```

Para ello dentro de la app, cree la carpeta templatetags, con su _*init_*.py correspondiente y metí ahí el filtro.  Luego lo use en la template:

```
{% load custom_template_tag %}
```

y su correspondiente aplicación al campo:

```
<td>{{object.enddate|timestamp_to_date|date:'DATETIME_FORMAT'}}</td>
```

Un saludo